# Regex to match after string before space using RE2

Tags: regex, go, re2

I am new to RE2 syntax regex, I want to match first word comes after specific string.

For example:

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  Error sending periodic event
java.lang.NullPointerException: Java heap space
  Error sending periodic event`

I want to capture anything comes after `java.lang.` so I can get `OutOfMemoryError`, `NullPointerException` errors. I know in Python and PCRE we can do this using positive lookbehind and regex will be - `(?<=java.lang.).*?(?=\s)`, but this is not working for RE2.

Comment: You could use a capturing group instead of the lookbehind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
java\.lang\.([^\s:]+)
```

**Details**

- `java\.lang\.` - a `java.lang.` substring
- `([^\s:]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more characters other than whitespace and `:`.

**NOTE**: If you need to get all text between `java.lang.` and `:` followed with whitespace, use `java\.lang\.(.*?):\s`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fPfa2V/1) and the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/qslZPTFEsrL):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    regex := regexp.MustCompile(`java\.lang\.([^\s:]+)`)
    result := regex.FindStringSubmatch("java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Error sending periodic event")
    fmt.Printf("%q", result[1])
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. What if we just want to capture fist instance. for example - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  Error sending periodic event java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at ----------------------Here we have 2 occurrences of OutOfMemoryError error, But i just want first one.

Comment: That is what `FindStringSubmatch` does, it matches and captures the first occurrence.

Comment: I am using it in stackdriver where i can just put my regex and not this code. I can not use this function there.

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil `(?s)^.*?java\.lang\.([^\s:]+)`